# Magento observer - Which event to use when a coupon code is canceled

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am building a module that adds a free product to the cart when a specific coupon code is entered.

I have an event observer which fires when a new coupon code is applied in the basket:
The event in my config is this:

```
<events>
    <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <checkoutApplyCouponToProduct>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Sulman_Giftwithcoupon_Model_Checkout_Observer</class>
                <method>applyCoupon</method>
            </checkoutApplyCouponToProduct>
        </observers>
    </salesrule_validator_process>  
</events>
```

This works correctly and I can add the free product succesully if the correct coupon code is added.

Now what I need to do is to remove the free product if the coupon code is canceled by the customer.

But the event I'm using does not fire when the coupon is canceled.

Is there an event I can use to check if the coupon code is removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably observe the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` event and check whether the `remove` param is set, which is what triggers `Mage_Checkout_CartController::couponPostAction` to remove the coupon.

**etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost>
                <observers>
                    <checkoutRemoveCouponProduct>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Sulman_Giftwithcoupon_Model_Checkout_Observer</class>
                        <method>removeCoupon</method>
                    </checkoutRemoveCouponProduct>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
public function removeCoupon(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action $controller */
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    if ($controller->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
        // @TODO add logic to remove free product
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That event covers both adding and removing a coupon :)

Comment: @sulman - In a sense it does happen during both adding and removing, however you should not use this event to mean “a coupon has been added” since at this point in execution the coupon would not yet have been validated and applied to the quote. So you would just be assuming that the code entered is correct.

Comment: Good point. In my case this isn't too bad. But I do have to do some validity checks to ensure all OK (valid customer group, in date etc). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can fire your custom event in `couponPostAction()` action in

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

in this you will see a code which handles the wrong coupon and also if the coupon form has no value. You can fire your custom event there and listen that event in your module.
Hope this will do your work.
thanks

Comment: you will see                 $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.'));
  in this function and above this line you can fire your custom event